# How to get timestamp to a specific day in 2 weeks

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am struggling abit to figure out how to set invoices raised on a specific timestamp to a friday two weeks in the future. This is an example data of how I would like each transaction to be set to be paid 2 weeks in the future on a Friday. I have some invoices that need to be set on a Thursday too. How would I go about to take the timestamp of each invoices raised in the week, to have a date set 2 weeks friday? or Thursday?

I tried this which works at setting the date as the Friday in 2 weeks, but goes wrong because it starts the week on a Sunday instead of Friday

```
DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL (25 - WEEKDAY(timestamp)) DAY) AS pd

Timestamp   Due date
2015-01-01  2015-01-22
2015-01-02  2015-01-22
2015-01-03  2015-01-22
2015-01-04  2015-01-22
2015-01-05  2015-01-22
2015-01-06  2015-01-22
2015-01-07  2015-01-22
2015-01-08  2015-01-29
2015-01-09  2015-01-29
2015-01-10  2015-01-29
2015-01-11  2015-01-29
2015-01-12  2015-01-29
2015-01-13  2015-01-29
2015-01-14  2015-01-29
```

Comment: Hi, did you get a chance to look over my answer below? Any feedback on it? If it's what you were looking for could you please mark it as the right one? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD( <<your_date_here>> , INTERVAL 2 WEEK),INTERVAL (6-DAYOFWEEK(<<your_date_here>>)) DAY)
```

should do the trick( if what you want is your_date + 2 weeks and next friday from that ).

If what you want is 2 fridays into the future it should be:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD( <<your_date_here>>,INTERVAL (6-DAYOFWEEK(<<your_date_here>>)) DAY) , INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Did this do the trick for you?

Later edit:

```
 SELECT DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( '<<your date here>>', INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK('<<your date here>>') > 5 ,16 , 14) DAY ), INTERVAL 6 - DAYOFWEEK( DATE_ADD( '<<your date here>>', INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK('<<your date here>>')>5,16,14) DAY )) DAY );
```

I explain :
    DATE_ADD( '<< your date here>>', INTERVAL IF(DAYOFWEEK('<< your date here>>') >5 ,16 , 14)
You add 14 days if the day of week is from Sunday to Thursday and 16 days if it is Friday or Saturday( in order to force it into the next week.
Now to this you again add the number of days necessary to reach Friday.

The example in your original question is wrong:
The 1st of January 2015 was in a Thursday so you add 14 days( 15 Jan 2015) + 1 so you reach Friday(16 Jan 2015).
2nd Jan 2015 was a Friday but, according to your wishes, you consider Friday the beginning of the work-week so you're looking for the 3rd Friday into the future( 23 Jan 2015 ).
3rd Jan 2015 -> 23rd Jan 2015
4th Jan 2015 -> 23rd Jan 2015
.
.
.
8th Jan 2015 -> 23rd Jan 2015

9th Jan 2015 -> 30th Jan 2015
10th Jan 2015 -> 30th Jan 2015
...
and so on and so forth.

Comment: No I am getting the wrong results. 2015-01-03 is showing as 2015-01-29 when it should be 2015-01-22 and it is counting Sundays as a new week instead of Monday

Comment: Yeah it looks like I am getting the wrong results because the week is starting from Sunday instead of Thursday sorry. So what I want is week is from Friday to Thursday. Everything in this period to be processed in two weeks Friday as the example above

Comment: Hold on.. I ll look into it as soon as i get to work.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, you have a date "x". You want x + 14 days. If x + 14 days =Thursday, you output that, otherwise you output the closest Thursday into the future?

Comment: No I want everyday between Friday - Thursday 1st - 7th, to provide a date of 22nd which is two weeks Friday. So working week is between Friday to Thursday and everything processed in between that week, is processed for payment for the weekafter Friday

Comment: ok, I'll look into if after work and provide a working answer for other people to see...